# SQL Query to pick specific string from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with the following data:

| Brand |
| --- |
| (NORLANE) MADDERN 1200 (CONTEMPORARY 1 FACADE) |
| **do not use**ASCENT 2600 ASPEN |
| **do not use**EVOLUTION 2300 ONTARIO |
| **do not use**MERCHISTON 3800 TRADITIONAL |
| AERO 1600 BLAKE |
| ALBANY 1700 ASPEN (GENESIS) |
| Albion 161 - Matisse - Discontinued |
| Alexander 159 - Coastal |
| Almeda 344 - Huntington |
| Mendelsohn 234 Swift - Drysdale |

Need to pick the specific string as output

| Brand |
| --- |
| MADDERN 1200 |
| ASCENT 2600 |
| EVOLUTION 2300 |
| MERCHISTON 3800 |
| AERO 1600 |
| ALBANY 1700 |
| Albion 161 |
| Alexander 159 |
| Almeda 344 |
| Mendelsohn 234 |

Following is the script of the table:

```
SELECT *
INTO  #tmpTest
FROM
(
SELECT '(NORLANE) MADDERN 1200 (CONTEMPORARY 1 FACADE)' Brand
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**ASCENT 2600 ASPEN'
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**EVOLUTION 2300 ONTARIO'
UNION ALL
SELECT '**do not use**MERCHISTON 3800 TRADITIONAL'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'AERO 1600 BLAKE'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ALBANY 1700 ASPEN (GENESIS)'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Albion 161 - Matisse - Discontinued'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Alexander 159 - Coastal'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Almeda 344 - Huntington'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Mendelsohn 234 Swift - Drysdale'
)R

SELECT * FROM #tmpTest
```

I have tired with CHARINDEX of with space

```
CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@str)) ,RIGHT(@str,CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@str))-1)
```

But not returning proper output.

Comment: What's the logic behind choosing these specific substrings? Seems like you want to get the first number and the word before it, but that's only a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption your output requirement is to

1. Remove the "do not use" text
2. Ignore the first word in parenthesis if it exists
3. Take the next two text elements delimited by a space

You can apply each successive step in a series of *cross apply* that each builds on the previous result.

Note this is possibly not the final working solution you'll need since it's based only on the sample data you've supplied, but it a good way there:

```
select Left(s2.s, p2.p) as Brand
from #tmpTest
cross apply(select Replace(Brand, '**do not use**',''))s1(s) /* Source string with text removed */
cross apply(select CharIndex(' ', s1.s))p1(FirstSpace) /* Find the pos of first space */
cross apply(select CharIndex(')', s1.s))b(ClosePar) /* Find pos of first close parenthesis */
cross apply(select Iif(ClosePar < FirstSpace and ClosePar > 0, Stuff(s1.s, 1, ClosePar + 1, ''), s1.s))s2(s) /* Remove content up to first closing parenthesisif relevant */
cross apply(select CharIndex(' ', s2.s, FirstSpace + 1))p2(p); /* Pos of second space */
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. It helped but what if we have multiple columns and this need to be linked with other table as JOIN which is having the clean data.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means and there's nothing about it in your question - by all means though ask a new question and explain further.

Answer (score 0):

As an example :

```
SELECT RIGHT(Brand, LEN(Brand) - CASE PATINDEX('**do not use**%', Brand) WHEN 1 THEN 15 ELSE 0 END)
FROM   #tmpTest
```